# no implicit conversion of GraphQL::Client::List into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть такой рабочий код:

```
field :tteesstt, types[types.String] do
    resolve(lambda do |obj, _args, _ctx|
        ["First", "Second"]
    end)
end
```

С ним все как надо. В результате отображается красивый массив.

Но есть такой код:

```
field :tteesstt, types[types.String] do
    resolve(lambda do |obj, _args, _ctx|
        list_as_string = obj.node.other_tteesstt

        really_array = JSON.parse(list_as_string)

        really_array
    end)
end
```

Из-за него возникает ошибка:

> no implicit conversion of GraphQL::Client::List into String

Она возникает из-за этого кода:

```
JSON.parse(list_as_string)
```

Почему это происходит и как это исправить подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Очевидно, `list_as_string` это никакая не строка, и `JSON.parse` не знает, что с нею делать.

Comment: @D-side в переменной `list_as_string` лежит это: `"[\"First 1\", \"Second 2\"]"`. Из под `rails c` эта строка хорошо парсится.

Comment: Это не отменяет того, что я сказал. То, что `inspect` выводит нечто похожее на строку, не означает, что это строка. Возьмите отладчик, гляньте на класс этого значения, посмотрите на методы.

Comment: @D-side сделал. Пишет что строка `obj.node.other_tteesstt` это: `GraphQL::Client::List`.

Comment: Что, собственно, я и сказал с самого начала, банально прочитав сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: @D-side ой, разобрался. Надо было тип поменять у поля :) Я какого-то фига перепробовал все варианты кроме этого... Мда. Спасибо что натолкнули :)

Comment: .......`.to_s`?

Comment: @Nakilon нет. Вопрос уже решен.

Comment: Нет, не решен. `.to_s` работает?